# Is it possible to use an existing Trino cluster as a data source for a different Trino cluster?

Tags: trino

Say that I have access to a Trino cluster (call it Trino_external) that has connections to various data stores. I also have access to another data store (call it RDB_isolated) that I cant connect to through the original Trino cluster. Is it possible to create a local Trino cluster (call it Trino_local) that has connections to both  Trino_external and RDB_isolated so that I can run a single query that joins data from these two sources? Something like this:

```
Trino_local
+- Trino_external
|  +- DB_external_1
| 
|__RDB_isolated
```

Sample query

```
SELECT *
FROM Trino_local.Trino_external.DB_external_1 as l
JOIN Trino_local.RDB_isolated as r
ON l.column = r.column
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you already explored just creating a 2nd catalog to your 2nd data source thus performing a federated query in your single Trino engine.  I'm further assuming that your 2nd cluster can access the additional datasource and that cluster 1 and cluster 2 can route traffic between each other.

With that, I'm not sure naked-Trino has an easy solution.  With Starburst, you could use the generic JDBC connector, https://docs.starburst.io/latest/connector/starburst-generic-jdbc.html, but more appropriately you could use Stargate, https://docs.starburst.io/latest/connector/starburst-stargate.html, whose whole mission in life is the technical use case your question has asked about.

Of course, this isn't all open-source Trino and there is licensing costs included in either of these solutions.

Comment: Granted, creating a 2nd catalog would be the ideal approach. However, the issue with creating a second catalog is that I would have to have access to an account on 'DB_external_1'. If the only way for me as an end-user to access that data source is through 'Trino_external', then I'll have no way to create a catalog to 'DB_external_1' in the 'Trino_local' cluster. I was aware of the Starburst solutions, but this was me investigating a potential use case that required naked-Trino. Still, good to know all the posibilities!